# How can I change an imagePath to a file?

Tags: file, flutter, path, filepath, temporary-files

I took a picture and it gets stored in a temporary directory so it can then be viewed on a preview screen before posting it. I'm trying to figure out how I can turn this imagePath into a file so it can be stored in Firebase.

This is the function to take the picture

```
_onCapturePressed(context) async {
    // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,
    // catch the error.
    try {
      // Attempt to take a picture and log where it's been saved
      final path = join(
        // In this example, store the picture in the temp directory. Find
        // the temp directory using the `path_provider` plugin.
        (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
        '${DateTime.now()}.png',
      );
      //print(path);
      await controller.takePicture(path);
      imagePath = path;

      // If the picture was taken, display it on a new screen
      Navigator.push(
        this.context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => displayStoryUploadScreen(),
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

This is the displayUploadScreen function that previews the picture.

imageFile is passed through "body:"

```
displayStoryUploadScreen() {
    print(imagePath);
    //Navigator.pop(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue),
        title: Text(
          "Preview",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.blue,
            fontSize: 22.0,
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.done,
              color: Colors.blue,
              size: 30.0,
            ),
            onPressed: () => controlUploadAndSave(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      // The image is stored as a file on the device. Use the `Image.file`
      // constructor with the given path to display the image.
      body: Image.file(File(imagePath),
        //decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: FileImage(file), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is the save function that I need help with. I need to get the imagePath to be a file so this part can work and I can add the logic to save photos to Firebase.

```
controlUploadAndSave() async {
    setState(() {
      uploading = true;
    });

    await compressingPhoto();

    String downloadUrl = await uploadPhoto(file);

    savePostInfoToFireStore(url: downloadUrl);

    setState(() {
      file = null;
      uploading = false;
      storyPostId = Uuid().v4();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have done this already. Using `File(path)` returns a file from the given path.

Edit: More details based on extra info:

You should really be using more arguments, rather than values in your state, but ultimately that's up to you. Basically what you need to do is pass your `imagePath` as an argument (Or a `File(imagePath)`, if you don't want to convert it within the function) to `controlUploadAndSave`.

Also, you mentioned having issues with your `imagePath` being null. I actually don't know Flutter works when you pass a function to the page route. That's not normal, you should create widgets rather than functions that return widgets. You could, however, pass your `imagePath` as an argument here too.

The main issue is your use of functions rather than widgets. You should have a separate widget (with separate state if you need it) for your new screen (`ConfirmationScreen`). Then you can use something like:

```
MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => ConfirmationScreen(imageFile: File(imagePath)),
),
```

To send your image to this widget. Once you're done with that screen and want to go back to your previous screen, you can simply pop the navigator and optionally include a value. This value is returned as a future to where you called `Navigator.push`.

Comment: Okay so what am I doing wrong in the controlUploadAndSave function? file is null when I print it. I'm trying to figure out how to pass it through there @David

Comment: How are you passing the file to your `controlUploadAndSave` function? Are you using a variable in your state? Also, in `body`, you are simply creating an image widget. You never actually save this `File` anywhere

Comment: That's what I need help with. I'm not sure how to save this file on the preview screen 
 and pass the file to the controlUploadAndSave function. But I only created the image widget to view it (just in case you wanted to go back and retake the picture). I didn't want it to be saved unless save was pressed. Maybe I was thinking about the logic wrong and that's not possible.

Comment: Updated my answer with more details